# Как в discord.py сделать функцию которая будет выбирать один из двух вариантов?

Tags: python, discord.py

Пытаюсь сделать discord бота на python и хочу сделать функцию,которая будет рандомно выбирать либо "орёл" ,либо "решка",но не знаю как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку `random`. Через нее уже куча вариантов решения, примеры:

---

**Через выбор из списка:**

```
import random
variants = ['орел', 'решка']
print(random.choice(variants))
```

---

**Через случайное число:**

*Этот метод стоит использовать, когда вам нужно изменить шансы, то есть не только 50 на 50*

```
import random
choice = random.randint(0, 100) # случайное число от 0 до 100
if choice < 30:
   print('Первый вариант (шанс выпадения 30%)')
else:
   print('Второй вариант (шанс выпадения 70%)')
```

---

Сама функция может быть оформлена примерно так:

```
import discord, random
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def орел_решка(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.choice(['орел', 'решка']))

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

*Ну или другими методами.* Вызов функции в чате дискорда: `!орел_решка`

**Не забудьте указать ваш токен в конце!**